# Many to one mapping

Tags: nhibernate

I have a tabel that looks like,

*tabel1*

someID PK,
node

*tabel2*

nodeID PK,
node

and I am trying to make to make the following in nhibernate instead of sql

```
SELECT *
FROM tabel1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tabel2 
ON tabel1.node = tabel2.nodeid
```

I have tried (and it is a many to one relation because Tabel2 can have several Tabel1 relations)

Tabel1 mapping file

```
        References(x => x.Tabel2)
            .Column("nodeID")
            .Not.LazyLoad();
```

Tabel2 mapping file

```
        HasMany(x => x.Tabel1)
            .KeyColumn("node")
            .Not.LazyLoad();
```

I dont get why this is not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Column("nodeID")` has to be `.Column("node")` because it is the column in table 1 pointing to the id (default) of table2

Comment: That sounds reasonably but it still dosent work. This gives me a headache :) "Invalid column name 'node_id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Node_id'."}

Comment: are you sure it is the HasMany mapping you posted? the error sounds more like the default KeyColumn generated if nothing is specified

Comment: I ended upp with your solution and now it works, probably changed something else to..

            References(x => x.Tabel2)
                .Column("DossierNumber");
 and 
            HasMany(x => x.Tabel1)
                .Not.LazyLoad();